# Extending ArcGIS

Tags: java, python, visual-studio-2010, arcgis, arcobjects

I've been tasked with a thesis project where i have to extend the features of ArcGis. I've been asked to create a model written in Python that can run out of ArcGIS 10. This model will have a simple user interface where the user can drag/drop a variety of shapefiles and enter the values for particular variables in order for the model to run effectively. Once the model has finished running, a new shapefile is created that lays out the most cost effective Collector Cable route for a wind turbine from point A to point B.

I'd like to know if such a functionality/ extension already exists in ArcGIS so i don't have to re-invent the wheel. If not then what is the best programming language to learn to extend ArcGIS for this (Python vs Visual basic vs Java). My background is Java, PHP, Jquery and Javascript. Also any pointers in the right direction i.e documentation, resources etc would be hugely appreciated

Comment: Maybe this would be better asked at: http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You must understand EXACTLY how it should work and where the tool should place all input and output datasets, their structures, attribute table fields and so on.
There is only one person who knows all these stuff - and it is You.
And it is not "the wheel", but it is a custom tool. You can build a model in built-in model builder (the great thing) and then export the model into a Python script.

Check this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBSXBqEP-7Y

And again. You have to know: 1) Input datasets and parameters 2) What do you want to get as the output 3) How it should work

Answer (score 0):

I do stuff like this every day for my day job in customizing ArcGIS for utility companies like gas, water, and electric.  We create buttons for them that does similar things like - draw a service gas line from the gas meter point on the side of the house to the nearest point on the nearest gas main line, split the main at that point, insert a "T" point feature, and connect the service line from the "T" to the meter.

We mostly use C# and a bit of VB.net.  You may want to look into creating a Python Add-in for something like ArcGIS Explorer.  Or an Add-in for ArcMap.
Explorer and ArcMap let you add shapefiles as layers in the map.  Add-ins let you easily add a button to the toolbar that can do things to the features on the map like query their attributes and modify their attributes and geometry to move them around on the map, as well as create new features and fill out attributes and place them on the map with X,Y or Lat/Long.

So your "Calculate Best Cable Route" tool could be a button your create on the toolbar (ICommand) that would first:
1. let the users select point A and point B on the map using the built in selection tools in Explorer/ArcMap.
2. let the users click your custom ICommand button.
3. your ICommand.OnClick() method would then execute all the code to try different routes based on geometry of other features on the map like street edges, building outlines, property lines, etc. then calculate the total cost like digging in dirt, asphalt, and getting permission/Right of way for cases where it goes over property lines.

See the ArcGIS ArcObjects API here to get started:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ICommand_Interface/00430000001s000000/

Comment: Here's a great video showing how to make a VB.net/C# add-in for ArcGIS Desktop (Explorer or ArcMap)  http://video.esri.com/watch/1888/building-add_dash_ins-for-arcgis-desktop-in-net

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Python AddIn is probably the quickest and easiest approach if you just want to do some geoprocessing and deploy the tool to lots of users.

But as soon as you need a user interface (that does more than simply select GIS data sources) you should create a .Net AddIn (using either C# or VB.net).

I've created many AddIns over the years and they are a dramatic improvement to the old ArcGIS "plugins" that involved lots of complicated COM registration. AddIns are easy to build and deploy. Easy for users to install and uninstall.

.Net has excellent, powerful features for creating rich user interfaces with the kind of drag and drop that you require. And there are great books, forums, samples to leverage.